# Break Role Inheritence Problem

Tags: document-library, permissions, powershell

I used following script provided by Nadeem for breaking permission inheritance of folder. but for me, when I tested ,it doesn't break inheritance at all. it is just assigning new group to the particular folder by keeping all original permissions. what I am missing here?

```
function GrantGroupPermission($groupName)
  { $PermissionLevel = "Full Control" ;
    $group = $web.SiteGroups[$groupName];   
    $folder.BreakRoleInheritance($false);
    $roleAssignment = New-Object microsoft.sharepoint.SPRoleAssignment($group);
    $roleDefinition = $web.RoleDefinitions[$PermissionLevel];
    $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add($roleDefinition);   
    $folder.RoleAssignments.Add($roleAssignment);       
    $folder.Update();  

   Write-Host "Permission provided for group ", $groupName

     }
```

Comment: Are you using `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates` anywhere in the script.

Comment: No. I already tried using that but it doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

I did the same using an item event receiver. I'll show what i did in c# code, but you'll have to do the same logic in your script.

First of all you can try a $folder.SystemUpdate() instead of the .Update(). This solved some issues for me.

Next you can write a foreach that will delete all the current permissions, and after this is executed if adds the permissions you want.

in C# the following code was used to delete the permissions:

```
SPRoleAssignmentCollection SPRoleAssColn = itemCurrent.RoleAssignments;
for (int i = SPRoleAssColn.Count -1, i >=0; i++)
{
SPRoleAssColn.Remove(i)
}
```

I guess you can use this logic in your scripting too.
Can you also check if the user that is editing the permissions, has the needed permissions to do this? In my case this wasn't so, and I need to use a RunWithElevatedPrivileges script.